# updating database with threading.Timer doesn't update it properly

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am working on a website.

When a user logs-in to the site from a new device, I mail a validation code to the user.

I don't want to resend new validation codes if user tries to log-in within 10 seconds because of failed log-in attempt.

So I am saving the device-id of the browser he tried to log-in from in the DB. And calling a function to clear the device-id's in the DB after 10 seconds.

I wrote the following code for that purpose:

```
code = validation_code
user_object.ip_validation_code = code
user_object.pre_validation_devices[device_used] = code

def clear_pre_validation_devices():
    user_object.pre_validation_devices = {}
    user_object.save()

Timer(30.0, clear_pre_validation_devices).start()
user_object.save()
```

After executing the code, I've found that this is not clearing the filed **pre_validation_devices** as I expected.

I am using Django 1.6 and Mongo DB, I will be grateful for any help.

Thank you

Comment: You should probably just use the [TTL](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/expire-data/) feature that is built in to Mongo.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  But I just want to remove a particular field from the document. Not the entire document.

Comment: I couldn't get this approach to work. So I found a workaround. I save the time when the validation code is generated. I find the time user tried to login. I find the difference. If the difference is less that 30 sec I wont send a new validation code.